# Which elliptic curves over totally real fields are modular these days?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

As the title says.  In particular, every elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ is modular; but what is the current state of the art for general totally real number fields?  I assume the answer is extractable from some papers of, say, Kisin, but I am not an expert in this material and hesitate to try that myself.

Comment: All of them are potentially modular (this is because there exists a rational prime l such that E has good ordinary reduction at every prime in F above l). To prove that a specific example is actually modular might be hard, as all the works I am familiar with assume either residual modularity or large image (but I am definitely no expert either).

Comment: But is one of those things enough?  For example, if the curve has an irreducible mod-3 representation, then you can get started via Langlands-Tunnell - but are other things required?

Comment: It is known (potential modularity + Solomon's induction theorem) that the $L$-function of any elliptic curve over any totally real field is meromorphic on ${\mathbb C}$ and satisfies the expected functional equation. For many applications this is as good as modularity, but I don't whether whether this is of help to you.

Comment: I've recently asked a similar question in case you are still interested. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96289/extensions-of-the-modularity-theorem

Answer (score 9):

Elliptic curves over real quadratic fields were proven to be modular very recently by Freitas, Le Hung and Siksek:

- Nuno Freitas, Bao Le Hung, Samir Siksek, [Elliptic Curves over Real Quadratic Fields are Modular](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.7088v4.pdf) (2015)

Some progress was alredy present in the thesis of Richard Taylor's student Le Hung.

- Bao Le Hung, [Modularity of some elliptic curves over totally real fields](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4134v1.pdf) (2013)

*Potentially modular* is known unconditionally over arbitrary totally real fields, that is:

> **Theorem.** Let $E/F$ be an elliptic curve over a totally real field. Then there is some totally real extension $F'/F$ such that $E/F'$ is modular.

As mentioned in the comments, for practical purposes this is almost as good as modularity.

The attribution of this theorem is complicated. There's some information about this in section 7 of our own Kevin Buzzard's very interesting survey on modularity:

- Kevin Buzzard, [Potential modularity—a survey](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.0097.pdf) (2011)

You can also consult:

- Jean-Pierre Wintenberger, [Appendix: Potential modularity of elliptic curves over totally real fields](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~wintenb/potmodcomp.pdf) (2010)

For arbitrary totally real fields, modularity is still not known.